# Solving knapsack with fractional knapsack approach

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

There are two well-known knapsack problems:

1) Given `n` items, each has its `weight` and `cost`. We need to select items, that will fit in our knapsack and have maximal cost in sum. It can be easily solved using `dynamic programming`.

2) Fractional knapsack: same as the first, but we can take not the whole item only, but its part. This problem can be easily solved with `greedy algorithm`.

Imagine we are using `greedy algorithm` from second problem to solve the first one. How can I prove, that the solution we will get is no more than two times worse, than the optimal one?

Comment: What do you mean by "worse"?

Comment: You probably have more restrictions, since general case (weight, cost are double values, not simply int values) is not so DP-friendly

Comment: @Alexander Anikin: `int` is *not a restriction* - just *scale up* my answer - knapsack with `1e100` volume; item `A` with `weight = 1` and `cost = 1` and item `B` with `weight = 1e100` and cost `1e100-1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far I can see, the greedy solution can be as much as inefficient as you want.
Imagine that you have a knapsack with capacity `1` and two (`n = 2`) items:

```
item weight cost density
------------------------
   A      ε    ε       1  <- greedy choice
   B      1  1-ε     1-ε  <- optimal choice
```

so the greedy algorithm takes `A` with `ε` cost when the optimal solution is
to take `B` with `1-ε` cost. The chosen (greedy) solution is

```
  (1-ε)/ε = 1/ε - 1
```

times inefficient than optimal one. Make `ε` as little as you want (say, `ε = 1e-100`) and have a very inefficient greedy solution.

**Edit**: in case of integer values only, just *scale* the sample above: you have a knapsack with capacity `X` and two (`n = 2`) items

```
item weight cost density
------------------------
   A      1    1       1  <- greedy choice
   B      X  X-1   1-1/X  <- optimal choice
```

in this case the greedy solution is

```
   (X - 1) / 1 = X - 1
```

times inefficient than optimal one. Finally, make `X` to be large enough (say, `X = 1e100`)

Comment: Yep, the real 2-competitive greedy algorithm needs to consider a solution consisting solely of the item with a fractional setting.

Comment: Yea, thank you! I understood, that it works with integers too. Thanks for nice contr-example!

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko: Very concise answer!

Comment: @Aleksandr Tukallo: you are welcome! Even if just *one item* (that's `B`) can't be split you can create a counter example with arbitrary large inefficiency. Even if `B` can be split but not into *small enough chunks* (we can't split gold atom into gold protons and neutrons) you can create the counter example

Comment: Possibly related, but with far less concise answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967159/continuous-knapsack-vs-0-1-knapsack